# Why is \thisrowno{} the name of the command to specify column number

Tags: pgfplots

The PGFPlots manual states this: `\thisrow{⟨column name⟩} or \thisrowno{⟨column index⟩}`.

In my understanding columns run vertical, rows horizontal.

So, I was wondering, if there was a deeper meaning behind the choice to name the command which specifies the *column*: `\thisrowno{}` (*this row number*)?

Edit:
To illustrate my confusion a bit:

```
%content of data.csv:
4,6,5
1,2,3
7,8,9
```

The zero (first) *column* of data.csv contains:

```
4
1
7
```

The zero (first) *row* of data.csv contains:

```
4,6,5
```

Yet when invoking `\thisrowno{0}` it gives:

```
4,
1,
7,
```

Given the name which refers to *row*, I would expect the function to result in the following output:

```
4,6,5
```

Of course the confusion only exists, if rows run horizontal and columns vertical, however, [Wikipedia: Matrix (mathematics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)) suggests that this should be the commonly accepted scheme. The example in Wikipedia states that:

```
 1 9 -13
20 5  -6
```

is a  2x3 matrix, consisting of two *rows* and three *columns*.

Comment: see explanation in pgfplots manual on page 57 (section 4.3.4 Mathematical Expressions And File Data): *A column is referenced
using the special command `\thisrow{<column name>}`*.

Comment: Thank for pointing to the right page in the manual. Could you elaborate a little bit, I still don't see anything on page 57 or 58 on why a _column_ number should be specified by a command that contains the name \this _row_ no. The name suggests it specifies _row_ number (horizontal) but it specifies _column_ number (vertical). I try to understand if there is any reasoning behind this name choice, meaning that I am missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pgfplots manual (version 1.16) says on p. 32:

> We can use \thisrow{⟨column name⟩} to refer to table columns. Here,
>   “this row” means to evaluate the table for the “data point which is
>   being read from the current row”.

One way to think about this is to consider `\thisrow` being a function that returns values from this row, and similarly for `\thisrowno`. This function tells you what is in this row in the column specified by a name, or an index.

Comment: I will look at \thisrow. In the meanwhile, I have added a bit more explanation as to why I am confused.

Comment: @MatthiasArras Does thinking of `\thisrow{<column>}` as `current row at column <column>` help? Or, in terms of your matrix, the entry `A_ij` is, given a fixed `i`, `\thisrowno{j}=A_ij`? "this" then means "current", so it returns the jth entry of the current (or "this") row.

Comment: I will try to see what `\thisrow{}` and `\thisrowno{}` actually return if they are not gobbled by `x expr=` or the like (single integer value or column or integers or whatnot) .